# Images don't move according to monitor display

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm experiencing problems with the image positioning of my website.
I've set it up to be in the correct spot in relation the background and my monitor size. However I tested it on screenfly today the result was different. My goal is to get the images to automatically move across the screen to fit a the needs of a bigger display if needed. 
So in summary what I am after is some code to make my images re-position for larger displays automatically.
The website url is [www.mustownit.com](http://www.mustownit.com)

The website I used to see my website on a larger display is [Screen Fly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//www.mustownit.com&w=1920&h=1080&a=1)

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  {{content_for_header}} 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0519/8985/files/dK8eAz1.jpg?6056);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  {{content_for_body}} 
  {{content_for_layout}} 
<div style="position:absolute"></div>
<span style="position: absolute; left: 243px; top: 161px;"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0519/8985/files/theinternetschoice.png?6056" width="614" height="76" alt=""/></span>

<div style="position:absolute"></div>
<span style="position: absolute; left: 112px; top: 14px;"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0519/8985/files/xuWE8Qe.png?6056" width="884" height="129" alt=""/></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Reposition where and how? Right now, you're using absolute positioning, so of course the images don't reposition based on window size. Please clarify your question.

Comment: You pretty much summed up what I want. I would like a snippet of code that would be able to keep my in the same relative spot of my page so for example. I have an image in the corner of my page on a small monitor, then comes along someone on a big monitor and the image is in the middle of the page all of a sudden. How can I stop this? Thank you for the response @EdCottrell

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific. If you use absolute positioning, the images will always be at the given coordinates. You need to specify exactly what image should be where, or we can't really help you.

Comment: Sorry for the very vague question, I'm looking for these images The "Must Own It" here http://i.gyazo.com/f53d9b09d98db19990e123d2f0652809.png to always stay in the top right corner of the page. Because when I tested it on a large monitor the image was all of a sudden in the middle of the page. @EdCottrell

Comment: I don't see that image in your HTML, but it sounds like you just need to change one of your absolute positions to set the `right` coordinate, instead of the `left`. If you could prepare a jsFiddle showing a couple of placeholder images, it would be easier to help.

Comment: Thank you @EdCottrell I figured out what the problem was from your help. Turns out the "Absolute" positions were causing my problem. I'm really out of it at the moment so thank you for persisting on helping me, dis-bite the lack of detail I could provide. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you mean ,
but I have solution it might be you need .
add this code to your CSS and try it

```
background-size : cover
```

you code will be :

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0519/8985/files/dK8eAz1.jpg?6056);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size : cover ;
}
</style>
```

If that's not what you need give me more explanation .
have a good day .